# What is the most performant way to get Childs of a configurable Product

Tags: configurable-product, product-attribute

In some cases you need the simples belonging to a configurable, or specific attributes of them.

Example1: the product types

Example2: the prices

Example3: 3 attributes at once (I assume this is harder to get performantly done)

Comment: http://vinaikopp.com/2014/06/09/preloading-for-scalabiliy/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've recently been struggling to find a performant way to achieve Example3's scenario while working on a script to validate/check some data.

The script inits mage and among other things grabs a collection of product with a matching attribute set - the following shows how $_products is instantiated in my example:

```
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter( 'attribute_set_id', '9' )
    ->addFieldToFilter( 'type_id', 'configurable' );
```

Initially I tried something along these lines:

```
foreach ( $_products as $product ) {
    $child_ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds($product->getId());
    foreach ( $child_ids[0] as $id ) {
        $child = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
```

Which is most certainly *not* performant as it loads additional models within yet another loop. Then I stumbled upon the following that seems to be a bit more performant:

```
foreach ( $_products as $product ) {
    $children = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
    foreach ( $children as $child ) {
```

I haven't yet had the chance to benchmark the differences but it seems noticeably faster, will log some stats and expand this answer when I get a chance!

Comment: Trade that `*` for `array('attr_code1','attr_code2',[...])` and you've got it.

Comment: Swapping * for an array of attributes requires you to run a query first to get the attributes (of the given attribute set) you need to return, right, assuming you don't know what attributes exist/need/want? So is that quicker than getting ALL attributes?